# How to display collective Slave ip address of Jmeter distributed tests on Single report?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have multiple slaves for running distributed Jmeter test , and after run I want single report which will display ip address of each slave running thread so that I can analyse report when performance slows down .

Please help me how can I achieve this . Is there any third party report tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get slave IP address appended to the .jtl result file as:

1. Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) to your Test Plan and add the following variable:

   - Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `IP`
   - Value: `${__machineIP()}`
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder) on all slave machines:

   ```
   sample_variables=IP
   ```

   Another ways to set this property are:

   - Pass it as a command-line argument via `-J` parameter during launching each JMeter slave
   - Pass it via `-G` parameter from JMeter master

Assuming above configuration you will have machine IP address added as a last column to JMeter results file, hopefully your third-party tool can deal with it.

References:

- [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function
- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: **Thank you very much , @Dmitri T**  , it worked fine . Please help me how can view this generated jtl file with ip address , I tried to view this in jmeter UI , but it giving me this error - "error loading result file " . Is there any third party tool to view this ip adress . I generated CSV file which displays ip for this but it taking "time stamp" field in  incorrect format like " 1.48E+12  ".

Comment: You can view it using MS Excel or equivalent (any application which can present CSV files in table form), I don't think any JMeter Listener has possibility to display custom fields.